# javascript select all certain li tags in its subgroup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got the following html:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu inner">
  <li class="dropdown-header" data-optgroup="1">Header1</li>
  <li class="selected" data-optgroup="1"></li>
  <li data-optgroup="1"></li>
  <li class="dropdown-header" data-optgroup="2">Header2</li>
  <li data-optgroup="2"></li>//note no selected class here
  <li data-optgroup="2"></li>
  <li class="dropdown-header" data-optgroup="3">Header3</li>
  <li class="selected" data-optgroup="3"></li>
  <li data-optgroup="3"></li>
</ul>
```

I need to select all `li` with class `dropdown-header` which have at least 1 `li` with class `selected` in its `data-optgroup` subgroup. In this case `Header1` and `Header3` should be selected. I can select all `dropdown-header` `li` tags, but I cannot select just those which have at least 1 li with `selected` class in their `data-optgroup`. Any ideas for the solution would be welcome.

Thank you

Comment: Please show an effort.

Comment: sorry for that, the question is about javascript only

Comment: That's as maybe, but you still need to show us what you've tried, otherwise you're essentially asking people to do the task for you.

Comment: Please define "_selection_" in the context. You need a collection or jQuery object of those elements? You've to highlight them on the page? Something else?

Comment: just an array of these `li` tags with `dropdown-header` class. In ths case Header1 and Header3, not Header2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `dropdown-header` element, you can use nextUntil() to extract the set of `li` between it and the next one...

```
var myTags = [];

$('li.dropdown-header').each(function() {
    if ($(this).nextUntil('li.dropdown-header').filter('li.selected').length > 0)
        myTags.push($(this).text());
});
```

I hope it helps